# Ati free driver and fan speed

Tags: drivers, ati, fan

I have a Sapphire 5850 GPU.

When I install any drivers in ubuntu for it my games run very heavy - with some strange glitches in the video.

I went back to the default driver and the games in steam run perfectly - but I can'tt control my fan speed with any command or tool.

All ask for CCC and the ati driver.
Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: `> All ask for CCC and the ati driver.` - what does this mean, I don't understand.

Comment: That the tools and the aticonfig or amd config require amd driver and controll center installed, which i dont want because the games dont run well. I have better graphics with the default driver but cant use aticonfig.

Comment: You can not use the proprietary ATI tools with the open source driver. The proprietary tools are meant to be used with the proprietary driver. Fan speed in the (default) open source driver is controlled by the open source driver. If you have a problem with the fan control you should report it as a bug at the radeon project http://www.x.org/wiki/radeon/ (or at least ask about it on their mailing list)

Comment: If the fan speed is controlled by the open source driver, there is no way to change it? I just dont want to install any drivers because all runs much better without them. Even the facebook games run soother with just the default driver.